# why the named parameter 'inputdataint' isn't defined and how to fix it in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, input, navigator

i am new to flutter. recently building a project of a timer app. ok the homepage is when the user open the app. it will enter a number for hours, minute and second they want to countdown. then this three numbers will be send to another page in a code line here

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: inputdataint),//inputdataint means the constructor i build. don't know correct or not
    );
  }
```

so the problem here is when I want to send the three numbers that input by the user and send it to the second screen that is the Countdowntimer screen it gives me an error of the inputdataint isn't defined. but I already defined the inputdataint in the class. can anyone help.
this is the error part

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>CountDownTimer(inputdataint:hourController.text )));
```

and this is my whole code. i don't know whether is my code got problem or maybe ...

```
class inputdatacountdown extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _inputdatacountdownState createState() => _inputdatacountdownState();
}

class _inputdatacountdownState extends State<inputdatacountdown> {

  final hourController = TextEditingController();
  final minuteController = TextEditingController();
  final secondController = TextEditingController();
  final _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  int inputdata;
  _inputdatacountdownState(){
    inputdata=int.parse(hourController.text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final nametext =
    MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
        ? Colors.white
        : Colors.black;
    final nametextonbutton =
    MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
        ? Colors.black
        : Colors.white;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Form(
              key: _key,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                      controller: hourController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'e.g 1',
                        labelText: 'hours',
                        border:
                        OutlineInputBorder(),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                          onPressed: () =>
                              hourController
                                  .clear(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      keyboardType:
                      TextInputType.number,
                      textInputAction:
                      TextInputAction.done,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'hours cannot be empty';
                        } else
                          return null;
                      }),
                  TextFormField(
                      controller: minuteController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'e.g 1',
                        labelText: 'minutes',
                        border:
                        OutlineInputBorder(),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                          onPressed: () =>
                              minuteController
                                  .clear(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      keyboardType:
                      TextInputType.number,
                      textInputAction:
                      TextInputAction.done,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'minutes cannot be empty';
                        } else
                          return null;
                      }),
                  TextFormField(
                      controller: secondController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'e.g 1',
                        labelText: 'second',
                        border:
                        OutlineInputBorder(),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                          onPressed: () =>
                              secondController
                                  .clear(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      keyboardType:
                      TextInputType.number,
                      textInputAction:
                      TextInputAction.done,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'second cannot be empty';
                        } else
                          return null;
                      }),
                  FlatButton(
                      color: nametext,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_key.currentState
                            .validate()) {
                          print(
                              'hour: ${hourController.text}');
                          print(
                              'minutes: ${minuteController.text}');
                          print(
                              'second: ${secondController.text}');
                          
                          Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>CountDownTimer(inputdataint:hourController.text )));
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'submit ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color:
                            nametextonbutton),
                      ))
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}

class CountDownTimer extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _CountDownTimerState createState() => _CountDownTimerState();
}

class _CountDownTimerState extends State<CountDownTimer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
    return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }
    int inputdataint;

  CountDownTimer(int inputdataint){
    this.inputdataint = inputdataint;
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: inputdataint),//come back to you later
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final nametext =
    MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
        ? Colors.white
        : Colors.black;
    final nametextonbutton =
    MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
        ? Colors.black
        : Colors.white;



    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: controller,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 1.0,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Positioned.fill(
                                  child: CustomPaint(
                                      painter: CustomTimerPainter(
                                        animation: controller,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        color: themeData.indicatorColor,
                                      )),
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        "Count Down Timer",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20.0, color: nametext),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        timerString,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 112.0, color: nametext),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedBuilder(
                          animation: controller,
                          builder: (context, child) {
                            return FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (controller.isAnimating)
                                    controller.stop();
                                  else {
                                    controller.reverse(
                                        from: controller.value == 0.0
                                            ? 1.0
                                            : controller.value);
                                  }
                                },
                                icon: Icon(controller.isAnimating
                                    ? Icons.pause
                                    : Icons.play_arrow),
                                label: Text(
                                    controller.isAnimating ? "Pause" : "Play"));
                          }),
                    ],
                  ))
            ]);
          }),
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening there is that you send an argument named `inputdataint` to your Widget `CountDownTimer` by doing so:

```dart
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>CountDownTimer(inputdataint:hourController.text )));
```

You can see there that you send the value `hourController.text` to the `CountDownTimer` as an argument called `inputdataint`.

The error came from the definition of your `CountDownTimer` widget definition.
You didn't declare the argument `inputdataint` but you are trying to use this value.

For doing so, you need to update your code like so:

```dart
class CountDownTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String inputdataint;

  const CountDownTimer({this.inputdataint});

  @override
  _CountDownTimerState createState() => _CountDownTimerState();
}

class _CountDownTimerState extends State<CountDownTimer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    // Your widget there...
    // Use widget.inputdataint to use the data your passed to this widget.
}
```